# Using delegates in OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, delegates, nsobject

I'm new at OS X development, I've been having a problem getting a delegate callback and I somehow suspect that it might be a memory problem. I have an NSViewController. In it's init method I am setting up a custom NSObject as so:

```
        MyObject *aManager = [[MyObject alloc] initManager];
    __theManager = aManager;
    self.theManager.delegate = self; 
    [aManager release];
```

the delegate I've setup as nonatomic, assign. Looking at the breakpoints I should be seeing the callback in my view controller but this never happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the code in MyObject that should be sending the delegate message. If that code gets hit, step line-by-line until you either reach the delegate message or see why you're not hitting it. If you do get to it, inspect the object's `delegate` property, and if it's set correctly, step into what should be the delegate message and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__theManager = aManager;` should be `self.theManager = aManager;`, assuming `theManager` is a retained property. The problem you have is that `alloc] init];` gives `aManager` a retain count of +1. `__theManager = aManager;` does not increase that count, as the iVar is set directly. When you release it, the retain count becomes 0, and so it is deallocated.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that unfortunately still no luck. I have again checked my breakpoints and I can see that [delegate doSomething]; is getting called.

Comment: @MarioPen So if the delegate **is** getting called, what is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't that is the problem.

Comment: Ok, this is getting very confusing, and I'm not sure what the problem is. What *exactly* is called, and what *exactly* do you want to be called? Please be very specific, as currently you are contradicting yourself.

Comment: The method in my custom object class MyObject that sets the call [delegate doSomething] is getting called. However going back to my NSViewController subclass I don't see that method being called, even though I have assigned the object's delegate properly.  In iOS this would have worked.